# Proper way a implementing property based on generic type

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have the following interface

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : IEntity, new()
{
    List<T> GetAll();
}
```

which i implemented here

```
public abstract partial class WhsePricingRatesAddOnProviderBase : WhsePricingRatesAddOnProviderBaseCore, IRepository<WhsePricingRatesAddOn>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all rows from the DataSource.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns a TList of Entity objects.</returns>
    public override List<WhsePricingRatesAddOn> GetAll()
    {
        return base.GetAll();
    }
}
```

AND ALSO HERE

which i implemented here

```
public abstract partial class WhsePricingRatesAddOn2ProviderBase : WhsePricingRatesAddOn2ProviderBaseCore, IRepository<WhsePricingRatesAddOn2>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all rows from the DataSource.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns a TList of Entity objects.</returns>
    public override List<WhsePricingRatesAddOn2> GetAll()
    {
        return base.GetAll();
    }
}
```

When I try to use it in a class

```
 public class TypeRate
    {
        public IRepository Repository { get; set; }

        public TypeRate(int i)
        {
    if (i == 1)
            {
                Repository = (IRepository<WhsePricingRatesAddOn>)SCMSDevMaster.Data.DataRepository.WhsePricingRatesAddOnProvider;}
    else
            {
                Repository = (IRepository<WhsePricingRatesAddOn2>)SCMSDevMaster.Data.DataRepository.WhsePricingRatesAddOn2Provider;}
            }
        }
    }
```

I either get this error if i dont put <T> after the IRepository declaration

> Using the generic type 'IRepository<T>' requires one argument.

or if i put it, then i get

> The type of namespace name 'T' could not be found error

I want my TypeRate class to be unaware of T until it's runtime creation, at which point i will set with code the proper T for the repository.

am I looking at this the wrong way ?

I should point out the **SCMSDevMaster.Data.DataRepository.WhsePricingRatesAddOnProvider** is static;

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your `Repository` property declaration - you just need to specify the type argument, which you can do directly given that you've only got one type which will work, by the looks of it:

```
public IRepository<WhsePricingRatesAddOn> Repository { get; set; }
```

I don't understand why you say you want `TypeRate` to be unaware of the type of `T`, as it's clearly set in the constructor...

You *could* make `TypeRate` generic too (i.e. make it `TypeRate<T>` and declare your property as `IRepository<T>`), but then the constructor body wouldn't compile, as it's explicitly casting to `IRepository<WhsePricingRatesAddOn>`.

It's possible that you could introduce a *non-generic* `IRepository` interface as a super-interface of `IRepository<T>` - but you've already got `IEntity`, and all you're adding is the `GetAll()` method which relies on `T`...

Fundamentally, I think you really need to decide what information is known at compile-time and what information is only known at execution-time - because it sounds like you have inconsistent requirements at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

This definition

```
public IRepository Repository { get; set; }
```

is not complete, because there isn't a class (or interface) called `IRepository`. There is a generic interface with one type parameter called `IRepository`, but that's another thing.

Declare the `Repository` with the concrete specified type, like this:

```
public IRepository<WhsePricingRatesAddOn> Repository { get; set; }
```

On the other hand, if you need the type of the repository to differ, the problem will be the line:

```
SCMSDevMaster.Data.DataRepository.WhsePricingRatesAddOnProvider
```

Which is as specific as it can get. I don't see how you can make that part dynamic without major redesigns, and I do not have enough info about your design to offer further advice.

Comment: I probably made my question too simple... I will have more than one Type (WhsePricingRatesAddon1, 2, 3) etc.. and I am trying to have a generic <T> and not a typed WhsePricingRatesAddon

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a generic method as opposed to a generic interface. Then, you don't have to declare your IRepository interface with a specific type.

```
public interface IRepository
{
    List<T> GetAll<T>() where T : IEntity;
}

public class TypeRate
{
    public IRepository Repository { get; private set; } 

    public TypeRate(IRepository repository)
    {
         Repository = repository;
    }
    public List<YourType> Get()
    {
        return this.Repository.GetAll<YourType>();
    }
}
```